# CSS span/div width different in firefox and chrome

Tags: css, width, rendering, html

Trying to get a gap in a line of text, like this:

```
Text: (absolute positioned field here) more text
```

In Chrome, it pushes it over just the right amount, so "more text" is just right of the field. In Firefox, it displays it too far to the left, so that the text is hidden behind the field.

I have an absolute-positioned field in between. "more text" is in a span, and I've tried positioning it using different units of measurement, as well as by using width, margin-left, and position:relative. The units of measurement just seem to be less in Firefox. This is basically what I have:

```
<div> Text <input /><span class="moveright"> more text </span> </div>
.moveright {display: inline-block; position:relative; left:160px}
```

Thanks for the help!

**edit: jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7jmP4/

In the fiddle I intentionally space it wrong to produce what I'm seeing. And if I view it in Chrome and Firefox it perfectly produces the problem that I have - in Firefox, "more text" is mashing into the text field on the top one.

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle.net please?

Comment: The fiddle doesn't look right in Chrome either.

Comment: In Webkit (Chrome/Safari/...) the `box-sizing` of `input` defaults to `border-box` which means that it's width already includes the padding and border. Gecko uses `content-box` and padding, borders etc. are added to the width. Apart from possible general differences in the default styles this may be the reason why it looks different in different browsers.

Comment: Try setting a width for your input, the auto width will vary browser to browser.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at the wrong thing. It was the input box that was wrong, not the span. Thanks!

Comment: @hsan's answer fixed it for me. should be the accepted answer imo.  thanks!